# Hadoop 2.2 on Ubuntu 12.04. Namenode wont't start. Why?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hadoop, hadoop2

I'm following this tutorial - http://www.ercoppa.org/Linux-Install-Hadoop-220-on-Ubuntu-Linux-1304-Single-Node-Cluster.htm

When I start the services. Namenode doesn't start. Following is my namenode log. I tried searching for the error on google, but couldn't find the solution. I tried deleting the namenode in the directory, even deleting the whole namenode-data-directory and formatting the namenode. But no luck. I'd appreciate your help.

```
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Lock on /home/username/hadoop/data/namenode/in_use.lock acquired by nodename 25382@username-HP-ENVY-15-Notebook-PC  
org.mortbay.log: Stopped SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:50070  
org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Stopping NameNode metrics system...  
org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system stopped.  
org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system stopped.  
org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system stopped.  
org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system stopped.  
java.io.IOException: NameNode is not formatted.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:210)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFSImage(FSNamesystem.java:787)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFromDisk(FSNamesystem.java:568)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.loadNamesystem(NameNode.java:443)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:684)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:669)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1254)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1320)  
org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1  
INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
```

Comment: I followed the same steps on my 32 bit machine and it worked.
But for some reason it is not working on the 64 bit machine.

Comment: did you try absolute path instead of ${user.home}

Comment: I used absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

What is the output in "format HDFS" step? The Exception message is clear:

`java.io.IOException: NameNode is not formatted.`

Comment: Apparently, there is no error message when I format Namenode. It says successfully formatted.

I highly doubt it is because my machine is 64 bit. But, I don't why.

Comment: I had install many times Hadoop 1.2.1, 2.4.0 y 2.5.0 on Ubuntu 12.04, 64 bit all the times, and not had any problem with the archiqueture. I had problems with ubuntu 14.04, but don't with NameNode Formatted.

Try to check the logs in namenode, perhaps yo find some additional message.